# Unable to show image in browser downloaded with AWS API Gateway but in Postman the image is shown

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I would like to show image from my S3 bucket on my website using AWS API Gateway. I followed this manual from AWS: [How do I upload an image or PDF file to Amazon S3 through API Gateway?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3)

If I would like to show the image with web browser ([link to image from API Gateway](https://cm57c518xh.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/pavel-kostal-book-cover/someJpeg.jpeg)) the web browser download some strange image that isn't possible to show. When I use Postman, the image is shown without any problem. I tried to download the image from web browser but it isn't possible to show it. Downloaded image from Postman works as expected.

There is no problem with uploading file with API Gateway because it doesn't show image in browser that I uploaded directly to S3 (using AWS console).

**API Gateway Setting:**

- In GET method in `Method Execution` -> `Integration Request` is set
  `Content Handling` to `Passthrough`.
- In GET method in `Method Execution` -> `Method Response` under Http Status 200 is set: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Content-type`
- In GET method in Method Execution -> Integration Response under `Http Status 200` is set: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `'*'`, `Content-type` to `'image/jpeg'`

In API Setting under `Binary Media Type` is set `image/jpeg`

In Postman and in Web Browser in Development Tool -> Network, when I click on the image from API Gateway the headers are:

- `Accept:`  `image/jpeg`
- `Content-Type:` `image/jpeg`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` `*`

[image: Chrome image headers]

**Note:** Api Gateway is deployed to lattest version, there is no problem with CORS (CORS is enabled)
If you need more information let me know.

**Update:** Recently I tried to recreate the GET request. It is not written in manual but when I add header to `Method Response` under `Response Header for 200` `Accept` and in `Integration Response` under `Header Mappings` I set `Accept` `image/jpeg` the image is correcly show in Postman without is it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue. [This article](https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/binary-content.html#:%7E:text=This%20means%20that%20it%E2%80%99s%20currently%20not%20possible%20to%20use%20the%20API%20Gateway/AWS_PROXY%20integration%20to%20return%20images%20that%20can%20be%20just%20included%20into%20a%20web%20page%20using%20the%20img%20tag.) has the best explanation I've found so far for why it doesn't work:

> ... although the documentation suggests that multiple content types can be specified in the Accept header for binary responses, it seems that this breaks the conversion. This makes the current implementation useless for browsers, which by default request complex Accept headers. **This means that it’s currently not possible to use the API Gateway/AWS_PROXY integration to return images that can be just included into a web page using the img tag.**

I hope they're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to write a relay/proxy to rewrite the hostname. But also ran into issues returning the images and fonts from the original request.

This worked for me. You need to have separate returns for each context-type.

dbdata is the source.  I hope this helps.

```
elif (path[-4:] == 'webp'):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
         'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
            'Content-Type': 'image/webp'
        },
        'body': base64.b64encode(dbdata).decode('utf-8'), 
        'isBase64Encoded': True
    }
elif (path[-5:] == 'woff2'):
    print("HERE")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
         'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
            'Content-Type': 'font/woff2'
        },
        'body': base64.b64encode(dbdata).decode('utf-8'), 
        'isBase64Encoded': True
    }         
else:
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
         'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        },
        'body': dbdata
    }
```